# JMeter master/slave across Ingress (Docker to Kubernetes) (how to get JMeter to only use one RMI port)

Tags: docker, kubernetes, jmeter

I have JMeter Master (5.3) running in a Docker container, triggered by a Jenkins pipeline containing a 'docker run' command. It communicates to JMeter slaves that are located in a Kubernetes namespace, with an Ingress controller to handle input. (For this trial I'm using just one slave but there may be multiple in the future)

The Docker JMeter Master container is aware of Ingress and can reference it by name or by IP address. From within the JMeter Master container I am able to ping the JMeter slave hostname and it is giving the Ingress IP address which I would expect.

Ingress in turn has the ability to communicate with the JMeter slave, but I can't get from JMeter Master to JMeter slave. I have set server.rmi.localport=80 on both sides, the JMeter slave seems to register port 80 in the logs.

The error from the JMeter Master is 'operation timed out (connection timed out)'. I'm not sure where to start looking?

(For reference, we cannot move JMeter Master into Kubernetes, but conversely the slaves need to stay in Kubernetes in order to provide the workload).

Edit: I've done some more investigation. The problem seems to occur that while the base RMI port is port 80, it's also trying to open port 81 and port 82. This will obviously fail as I've only got port 80 available through ingress.

So the question is now 'how do I tell JMeter to only use a single port for RMI'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an update to this, basically I've come to the conclusion that 'you can't do this'. While the ports can be opened on Ingress, RMI can't communicate over them. So even if I could get it all on one port, it still wouldn't work.

There is a 'RMI over HTTP' implementation but I wouldn't have first idea on how to put that into JMeter.

What I have done is add a small webserver to the pod, such that I can control JMeter through normal web calls. For example, the jmx file can be PUT on to the pod, and a GET command can retrieve the results. That way I can start the pod up in the relevant location, where it will wait for whatever tests we want to run. It's also extendable if I need additional functionality.